# MySQL date field not responding to ASC or DESC in query

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I'm trying to sort a table of dates into ascending or descending order, but I can't get it to do either. The query isn't giving a syntax error so I don't think it's that.

```
Server version: 5.7.28-0ubuntu0.18.04.4 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

mysql> select * from elections order by 'last_election' ASC;
+--------+-----------------+---------------+
| row_id | jurisdiction_id | last_election | 
+--------+-----------------+---------------+
|      1 |               3 | 2018-11-24    |
|      2 |               2 | 2019-03-23    |
|      4 |               5 | 2018-03-17    |
|      5 |               4 | 2017-11-25    |
|      6 |               1 | 2016-10-15    |
|      7 |               6 | 2017-03-11    |
|      8 |               7 | 2018-03-03    | 
|      9 |               8 | 2016-08-27    | 
|     11 |               9 | 2019-05-18    | 
+--------+-----------------+---------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Previous / other similar questions all say, "Your field type is text or varchar, duh!" but the field type is definitely date:

```
+----------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| row_id               | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| jurisdiction_id      | int(11) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| last_election        | date    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

How do I query the table so that last_election is in order?

Comment: You're attempting to sort by a constant (`'last_election'`). Remove the quotes around `last_election` or change them to backticks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be:

```
select * from elections order by `last_election` ASC
```

***Note type of quotes***

Because **' '** are for strings and backticks are for column names. So I guess you are trying to sort them by string that is not changing - therefore it works same as not having `order by` at all

Comment: `select * from elections order by last_election ASC` should also work

Comment: @AK_oz I'm working with mssql and there ordering by date is totally fine. Seems odd for it not to work in mysql

Comment: Yeah i think the thing that's confusing me most is that it isn't giving me a syntax error, AND it's not treating fields as a string either - it's doing *nothing*

Comment: This correctly identifies the problem - sorting by a constant string, but double quotes also make strings.  Use backticks (or just the plain column name)

Comment: using ` instead of ' or " seems to get it to have an effect - that edit made it work too. Now there are three solutions that all work

Answer (score -1):

Your query seems okay

Try below query.

```
select * from elections order by date(last_election) ASC;
```

If its work try to drop table and recreate it with proper field types.

Comment: This works, for some reason. When you say 'recreate it with proper field types' what field types are you recommending over 'date' for a field that stores dates?

Comment: The query is not ok and there is no need for OP to recreate their table.